# Another way of proving :$\int_{0}^{1}{x-x^3+x^5-x^7\over (1+x^4)\ln{x}}dx=-\ln{2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x-x^3+x^5-x^7\over (1+x^4)\ln{x}}dx=-\ln{2}$$

My try

$x-x^2+x^3+x^5-x^7=x(1-x^2)+x^5(1-x^2)=x(1+x^4)(1-x^2)$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x(1+x^4)(1-x^2)\over (1+x^4)\ln{x}}dx$$

Applying Frullani theorem

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x-x^3\over \ln{x}}dx$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}{x-x^3\over \ln{x}}dx=-\ln{2}$$

Comment: where do you find all this strange identities?

Comment: for a solution take a look at the integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{1+x^4}dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some one will be interested in that

We can show

$$ \int^1_0 \frac{x^a-1 }{\log x} dx =\log \left ( a+1\right)$$

Using differentiation under the integral sign.

Generally

$$ \int^1_0 \frac{x^a-x^b }{\log x} dx =\int^1_0 \frac{x^a-1-(x^b-1)}{\log x} dx =\log \left ( \frac {a+1}{b+1}\right)$$

Hence

$$ \int^1_0 \frac{x-x^3 }{\log x} dx =\log \left ( \frac {2}{4}\right)=-\log 2$$